# A method with an optional parameter

Tags: ruby, methods

Is there a way to make a method that can accept a parameter, but can also be called without one, in which case the parameter is regarded `nil` like the following?

```
some_func(variable)

some_func
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
def some_func(variable = nil)
  ...
end
```

Comment: Then, of course, one has to somehow differentiate between default nil and explicit nil (if it matters) :)

Comment: That's what the `def some_func(variable = (variable_was_not_passed = true; nil))` idiom is for.

Answer (score 20):

Besides the more obvious option of parameters with default values, that *Sawa* has already shown, using arrays or hashes might be handy in some cases. Both solutions preserve *nil* as a an argument.

**1. Receive as array:**

```
def some_func(*args)
  puts args.count
end

some_func("x", nil)
# 2
```

**2. Send and receive as hash:**

```
def some_func(**args)
  puts args.count
end

some_func(a: "x", b: nil)
# 2
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using `*arg` and `**arg` instead of just `arg`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 `*arg` collects the arguments as an array. Without the `*` you would have to call `some_func(["x", nil])`. `**arg` collects all named arguments. Without the `**` it would only accept either a single unnamed argument, or any number of named arguments.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a hash as argument and have more freedom:

```
def print_arg(args = {})
  if args.has_key?(:age)
    puts args[:age]
  end
end

print_arg 
# => 
print_arg(age: 35, weight: 90)
# => 35
```