# How to pass an optional method parameter as string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parameter-passing

I would like to call a method in Ruby, which has an optional parameter.

I tried some ways, but none of them is working.
Can you help me, how can I call this method?
I never used Ruby before, so please help me refine the question itself. I tried googling the problem, but I think I use the wrong terms.

I read this: [Ruby Methods and Optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234406/ruby-methods-and-optional-parameters) and this: [A method with an optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747905/a-method-with-an-optional-parameter), but with no luck.

The method looks like this:

```rb
def method(param1, param2, options={})
    
    ...

    if options["something"]
        ...
    end

    ...

end
```

I tried the call, for example, like this:

```rb
method("param1", "param2", :something => true)
```

With my tries, the code runs but does not enter in the `if` condition.
I would like to call this method in the way, that the codes in the `if` statement would be run.

Comment: `:something != "something"`. One is a `Symbol`, the other is a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are sending `symbol` (`:something`) instead of `string` key (`'something'`). They are different objects.

Change:

```
method("param1", "param2", :something => true)
```

to

```
method("param1", "param2", 'something' => true)
```

or handle in method by `if options[:something]`

Comment: And a not to myself: `"something"` isn't working. Just `'something'`.

Answer (score 0):

Call your method with the same param type, or if you want to be able to pass either symbol or string key you can handle that in your method.

```
def foo(a,b, opt={})
  if opt[:something] || opt['something']
    puts 'something'
  end
end
```

Now you can call this with string or symbol keys:

```
foo('a','b', 'something' => true )
#or 
foo('a','b', something: true )
```